# Is there exists a function $f \in L^2(0;1)$ satisfies $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^n f(x) dx=0$, $n=4,5,6,\ldots$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^3 f(x) dx=4$?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exists a function $f \in L^2(0;1)$ satisfies $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^n f(x) dx=0$, $n=4,5,6,\ldots$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^3 f(x) dx=4$?

My attempt: I have already proved this problem "Let $f$ in $L^2(a,b)$ such that $\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \varphi(x) dx=0$, for all $\varphi \in M$, $M$ is dense set in $L^2(a,b)$ then $f=0$."

I tried to apply this to find the solution.
We have $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^n f(x) dx=0$ and $\varphi(x)=x^n$ is a polynomial which is a dense set in $L^2(0,1)$ then $f(x)=0$.
So that $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^3 f(x) dx=0$ (!).

Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: $M$ is nowhere dense or dense?

Comment: sorry M is dense, I edited my post @geetha290krm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x)=x^{4}f(x)$. Note that $\int_0^{1} x^{n} g(x)dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2...$ which implies $\int_0^{1} h(x) g(x)dx=0$ for every polynomial $h$. Conclude that $g(x)=0$ and then conclude that $f=0$.
So we cannot have $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^3 f(x) dx=4$.

Comment: Interestingly, it proves that the space of polynomials which vanish at order $\ge 4$ at 0 is dense in $L^2(0,1)$.